# How to get the value of Upload from form.item in Antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Even though the file is uploaded antd Form.item rules throws error. Which mean it's not getting the value from Upload to the form.item how should i solve this error. Note im using antd latest version 4.x in which getFieldDecorator has been deprecated. And i also want to upload file manually.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button, Alert, Upload } from 'antd';
import { UserOutlined, LockOutlined, UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

import styles from './test1.module.css';
const Test1 = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    fileList: [
      {
        thumbUrl:
          'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png',
      },
    ],
  });

  const handleChange = (info) => {
    console.log(info);
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];

    // 1. Limit the number of uploaded files
    // Only to show two recent uploaded files, and old ones will be replaced by the new
    fileList = fileList.slice(-1);
    setState({ fileList: fileList });
  };

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(form.getFieldsValue());
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.login_page}>
      <Form
        name='normal_login'
        className={styles.form}
        form={form}
        onFinish={onFinish}
      >
        <Form.Item
          name='email'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please input your Email!',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input
            prefix={<UserOutlined className='site-form-item-icon' />}
            placeholder='Email'
          />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name='password'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please input your Password!',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input
            prefix={<LockOutlined className='site-form-item-icon' />}
            type='password'
            placeholder='Password'
          />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name='image'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'input Image',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Upload
            beforeUpload={(file) => {
              // console.log(file);
              return false;
            }}
            onChange={handleChange}
            multiple={false}
            listType='picture'
            defaultFileList={state.fileList}
          >
            <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
          </Upload>
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item>
          <Button type='primary' htmlType='submit'>
            Log in
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Test1;
```

Is there any way i can bind the onChange event listener of Upload with form.Item

Answer (score 13):

Use prop `getValueFromEvent` in `Form.Item` and pass the function returning a file object.

```
const getFile = (e) => {
  console.log('Upload event:', e);

  if (Array.isArray(e)) {
    return e;
  }
 return e && e.fileList;
};
```

and `Form.Item` for image will be like this

```
<Form.Item name='image' getValueFromEvent={getFile}>
         <Upload >
         ....
         </Upload>
</Form.Item>
```

and you can get all form values in onFinish

```
const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values)
}
```

for further refer [this](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-rule)

Answer (score 3):

You can use maxCount prop of Upload component. It will limit the upload file to specified value.

reference: [Upload Component](https://ant.design/components/upload/#API)